# How far into the temple did the Ethiopian eunuch worship?

Tags: acts

Deuteronomy 23:1
No one who has been emasculated by crushing or cutting may enter the assembly of the LORD.

Acts 8:27
So he started out, and on his way he met an Ethiopian eunuch, an important official in charge of all the treasury of the Kandake (which means "queen of the Ethiopians"). This man had gone to Jerusalem to worship,

38And he gave orders to stop the chariot. Then both Philip and the eunuch went down into the water and Philip baptized him. 39When they came up out of the water, the Spirit of the Lord suddenly took Philip away, and the eunuch did not see him again, but went on his way rejoicing.

Was the eunuch unsatisfied?
Did he think that there was something missing in his worship until he was baptised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, as most do, that the eunuch was a gentile then he would not have made it past the Gentile Courts of the temple.

There was a fence/wall called a [soreg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Warning_inscription) that created a boundary for the gentiles. You can see a sign they've found in Jerusalem at the same link.

This is why the people of Jerusalem are so upset at Paul. They think he brought someone into the Temple (Acts 21:28-29):

> 28 shouting, “Fellow Israelites, help us! This is the man who teaches everyone everywhere against our people and our law and this place. And besides, he has brought Greeks into the temple and defiled this holy place.” 29 (They had previously seen Trophimus the Ephesian in the city with Paul and assumed that Paul had brought him into the temple.)

Maybe when the eunuch says "What can stand in the way" (Acts 8:36) he is thinking of the soreg as a barrier to God's house.

You can see a diagram of the Temple Mount here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Was the eunuch unsatisfied? Did he think that there was something missing in his worship until he was baptized?

No. The Ethiopian eunuch, as a Jewish proselyte, was already on his way to Jerusalem to worship (v.27). But while he was traveling he happened to be reading a passage about the Messiah. At this point Philip, guided by Holy Spirit, joins the Ethiopian, begins to discuss the passage he is reading and explains how Jesus Christ fulfills this passage (v.29-35).

As Philip continues to expound on Jesus' role of salvation for mankind, the Ethiopian recognizes what he must do to earn his salvation (v.36). Because of his acceptance of Jesus as his savior, he is overjoyed in spirit (v.39).

(For a bit more information on this, see "Bearing Thorough Witness" chapter 7, paragraphs 14 & 15 under the subheading ["Do You Actually Know What You Are Reading?"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1102009049#h=20))

Answer (score 0):

**What was an Ancient Ivri (Hebrew) Fetsua (Eunuch)?** - Emasculated (פְצֽוּעַ) man.

**Deuteronomy 23:2 [MT]** "He shall Not (לֹֽא) Enter (יָבֹ֧א) **Who is emasculated (פְצֽוּעַ) by crushing (דַּכָּ֛א) or cutting (וּכְר֥וּת) Shafekah (שָׁפְכָ֖ה)** into-Assembly (בִּקְהַ֥ל) of YHVH (יְהֹוָֽה)."

- Becoming a Hebrew "Fetsua" (פְצֽוּעַ) or damaging male Shafekah (שָׁפְכָ֖ה)** was prohibited by Moshe (משֶׁה֙) in [Chapter 23, verse 2] in the scroll of "Devarim" (דְּבָרִ֗ים) known by English translations as the book of "Deuteronomy". **The English KJV, NIV, NASB translations of the Hebrew Torah change the verse-number & word-order of "Devarim" (דְּבָרִ֗ים) or "Deuteronomy".**

**Deuteronomy 23:1 [NASB]** :

> "No one who is **emasculated or has his male organ cut off** shall enter the assembly of the Lord."

**Deuteronomy 23:1 [NIV]** :

> "No one who has been **emasculated by crushing or cutting** may enter the assembly of the Lord."

**Deuteronomy 23:1 [KJV]** :

> "He that is wounded in the stones, or hath his privy member cut off, shall not enter into the congregation of the Lord."

Why does the Law of Moshe (Moses) get reversed by Yeshua (Jesus) in **Matthew 19:12-14** ? - Perhaps Jesus regarded a spiritual union between humans which creates only a philosophical understanding of God > greater than the physical union between humans which provides a tangible understanding of God in the creation of children.

**Matthew 19:12-14 [NASB]** :

> "For there are eunuchs who were born that way from their mother’s womb; and there are eunuchs who were made eunuchs by men; and there are also eunuchs who made themselves eunuchs for the sake of the kingdom of heaven. He who is able to accept this, let him accept it.”

**Matthew 19:12-14 [NIV]**

> "For there are eunuchs who were born that way, and there are eunuchs who have been made eunuchs by others—and there are those who choose to live like eunuchs for the sake of the kingdom of heaven. The one who can accept this should accept it.”

**Perhaps Jesus understood the ultimate loss of children by emasculated men took away worldly joy & blessings, causing Eunuchs to inherit a spiritual joy & blessing in the kingdom of heaven.**

**Acts 8:27-39** offers righteous Eunuchs hope in their salvation / spiritual union with the Assembly of YHVH.